# how to write a plugin to show content under new tab in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I refereed several ebooks and web tutorials to write a plugin that meets my requirement. However, I am still unable to do it. All I found tutorials show how to render content as widget or sidebar content or modify the content.

I need to get data from database show the content in front end of the website but only on  a particular page or tab in the site. Such as forum plugin can be configured to show under new tab.

In another word I need to create my own content type and display it in a tab. I think this is possible with wordpress [custom content](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/custom-content-type-manager/)

I don't need to edit template files. Anybody has idea? thanks..

Comment: you want to add a front end page, or a page under admin panel?

Comment: front page, under main menu in front page. not in admin panel

Comment: you will need need to play with code.

Comment: If we need to show content in admin panel, it can be done using method such as `add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "OSCommerce Product Display", "install_plugins", "OSCommerce-Product-Display", "oscimp_admin");` now I need my content to show under main menu. Do you have any idea to handle this?

Comment: you can use page templates for that. there are plenty of tutorial how to get specific contents in a page template. This way you can have whatever data you want to display in your page template, they will only show in the page you have assigned the template. And there are many tutorials about how to create a page template from plugin.

Comment: I think what you suggest is to change the template but I want to create a new content, actually in my case template(layout for all page should be same)